# Complex type 'service': The content model is not determinist

Tags: symfony

I'm getting this strange error with Symfony2. In localhost everything works fine but when I try it in my server I get this PHP error:

```
[06-Mar-2013 22:04:50 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message  '[ERROR 3070] complex type 'service': The content model is not determinist. (in file:////home/neuronas/public_html/miramos.tv/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd - line 75, column 0)
[ERROR 3070] complex type 'argument': The content model is not determinist. (in file:////home/neuronas/public_html/miramos.tv/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd - line 131, column 0)
[ERROR 3070] complex type 'call': The content model is not determinist. (in file:////home/neuronas/public_html/miramos.tv/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd - line 144, column 0)' in /home/neuronas/public_html/miramos.tv/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php:370
Stack trace:
#0 in /home/neuronas/public_html/miramos.tv/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php on line 370
[06-Mar-2013 22:13:36 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message '[ERROR 3070] complex type 'service': The content model is not determinist. (in file:////home/neuronas/public_html/miramos.tv/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd - line 75, column 0)
[ERROR 3070] complex type 'argument': The content model is not determinist. (in file:////home/neuronas/public_html/miramos.tv/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd - line 131, column 0)
[ERROR 3070] complex type 'call': The content model is not determinist. (in file:////home/neuronas/public_html/miramos.tv/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd - line 144, column 0)' in /home/neuronas/public_html/miramos.tv/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php:370
Stack trace:
#0 in /home/neuronas/public_html/miramos.tv/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php on line 370
```

It seems to be something about XMLFile Loader, but I made no changes in his file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a bug in libxml2 - are you using RHEL or CentOS? Check out https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2013-0591.html and if you can't wait for the update to be released through `yum update`, then you can downgrade to an earlier version:

`yum downgrade libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.21.el5_9.1`

Huge thanks to @denkiryokuhatsuden on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7291) for the fix.

Comment: On a lighter note, I always suspected that some of my code might be non-deterministic, so it was kind of amusing to have this confirmed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's great to get this confirmed