# Symfony deployment

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to deploy my symfony 2.2 web site but i got problem:

> InvalidArgumentException: [ERROR 3070] complex type 'service': The content model is not determinist. (in file:////home/dir/fold/katalog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony.....

I try all the method but all time i got error.
I check my server configuration with domain/config.php and it is fine.
Next, i transfer all my folder without 'vendor' directory and with empty cache.
I execute php composer.phar install
          ......
But when i try domain/app.php/ => error(debug=true)
Finally , i transfered all my project including vendor, cache ... But the same thing =>Error

There same one can help me by short tutorial without the symfony documentation .
Thanks guys

Comment: which operating system on your server ?

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260017/complex-type-service-the-content-model-is-not-determinist

Answer (score 2):

This most likely relates to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260017/complex-type-service-the-content-model-is-not-determinist) question / solution and is caused by an error in libxml  when validating xsd of xml configuration files.

The original source of the solution is this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7291).

### Solution

**up- or downgrade your server's libxml2 to resolve the issue.**

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in libxml2 - are you using RHEL or CentOS? Check out https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2013-0591.html and if you can't wait for the update to be released through yum update, then you can downgrade to an earlier version:

yum downgrade libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.21.el5_9.1